# Jquery works locally, but not when online (failed to load resource)

Tags: jquery, web

So I´m creating website and I´m using jquery for two items, an image slider and twitter feed, and neither is working. And while everything works perfectly fine locally, it isn´t working online.

http://www.menucool.com/slider/jquery-slideshow - Slider
http://seaofclouds.com - Twitter feed

My webpage is currently www.nerodesign.is , a placeholder site. 
As you can see the results are not as expected. The very large stock images are supposed to be in confined to the imageslider frame.

The error given is Failed to load resource: The server responded with an error (404).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

ok there the files that missing, maybe the files were not uploaded

please compare and fix it with the setup with your offline resources

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery.tweet.css link is broken

Answer (score 0):

This CSS file here is not available:
http://www.nerodesign.is/jquery.tweet.css

The same goes for this js. Make sure that you reverence to the correct director and the file. 
script src="imgslider/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"

Remove the imgslider from the src and try again:
< script src="js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript" >

Please compare your offline file hierarchy with the online one and make sure you use absolute paths where needed

Answer (score 0):

Your css and javascript are missing. You need to upload them to the respective locations.

[image]